# Hive Column level encription with spark java

Tags: java, hadoop, encryption, apache-spark, hive

I have created connectivity between java spark and hive, my code is working perfectly. I am able to make crud operation with my code. Now i need to perform some encryption algo on few hive columns. I googled and found AES algo is good for encryption. But not able to get advance and highly secured way to encrypt hive columns. 
I am new for bigdata. if anybody have good document, or can give some thoughts, that would be very helpful for me. 
For data insertion i am using sql query. so i can easily use UDF.

My thought is: first i will create a custom algorithm for encryption and use in data insertion operation.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used AES encryption, and customized that algo as per my requirements.

Comment: I'm working on a similar requirement. Can you share design/code/approach you used to encrypt Hive columns through Spark? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per my initial hunt, I could see a couple of patches from hive available for column level encryption using the standard encryption types like Base64 included in Hive API and used in 'column.encode.classname' attribute during Create table time to encrypt the column data.

I haven't practically tested it on my environment yet and in progress. But if any of the below works, we can go a head with our own Encryption class implementation with  a standard encryption mechanism like AES by extending super Type , in other words mocking the CryptoRewriter and using it in the DDL command.

Example I referred from patch:

```
create table student_column_encrypt (s_key INT, s_name STRING, s_country STRING, s_age INT) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('column.encode.columns'='s_country,s_age', 'column.encode.classname'='org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.crypto.CryptoRewriter') 
  STORED AS TEXTFILE TBLPROPERTIES('hive.encrypt.keynames'='hive.k1');
```

Reference links :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8049

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6329